# Password method changed on nexus 4

Tags: lock-screens, 4.2-jelly-bean, nexus-4, lost-phone

I just got a nexus 4 and have been trying out a couple of 'lost phone' apps. I was using the face/pattern authention for the lockscreen, but now it prompts for a password. I tried my google account password and I still can't get on.

I'm not really sure what caused this, but I'd obviously like to get back on my device. How can I recover (or reset) my password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prompt for the password is probably caused by one of those apps. Try to remember the password you may have used for them.
 Or else please provide a list of the apps you've tried. (This can be achieved by going to the Google Play website and clicking on my apps. 
As a last resort you can restore your phone to it's factory settings by entering the recovery. 
To boot into the recovery press and hold power and volume up

Comment: I ended up doing a hard reset. The problem actually happened after I removed the apps(`Android Lost` and `Wheres My Droid`). I also had prey installed, but the password from that didn't on the phone, but it did on the site.